# Access stage elements from sub classes

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

The question is simple: **Access stage** objects (like Movie Clip or text fields) **from sub classes**.
The problem came when I define a subclass and try to access stage objects. How can I do that?
Imagine I have a movie clip named redBox_mc on the stage.I want to change it`s alpha after I get my xml loaded.(or any other action in subclass)

Main class:

```
package src{
   // ..
   public class code01 extends MovieClip {
     public var rt:xmlReader = new xmlReader("art.xml"); // my subclass 
     public function code01():void {
     // .. my code
     }
   }
}
```

xmlReader subclass:

```
package src{
    // ..
    public class xmlReader extends MovieClip {
        // ..  
        public function xmlReader(xmlFilename:String)
            // .. my code
                stage.redBox_mc.alpha =  .2 ; // doesn’t work
                MovieClip(parent).redBox_mc.alpha =  .2 ; // doesn’t work
        }
    }
}
```

Please help me ..

Comment: I answered your question below giving examples of how to make the stage accessible to an object's class that subclasses `DisplayObject`(option 2) as well as to any child object's class.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are many ways to make the stage accessible to a child object's class:

**OPTION 1**

The simplest way is to parse a reference of the stage to a child object's class:

Main.as(document class):

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class Main extends Sprite
    {
        public function Main()
        {
            if(stage) init()
            else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

        }// end function

        public function init(e:Event = null):void
        {   
            var foo:Foo = new Foo(stage);

        }// end function

    }// end class

}// end package
```

Foo.as:

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.Stage;

    public class Foo
    {
        public function Foo(stage:Stage)
        {
            if(stage) trace("success"); // output: success

        }// end function

    }// end class

}// end package
```

**OPTION 2**

Another option is that you add the display object to the display list. By doing this, your display object's class will have a reference to the stage. You then have to add an event listener within your display object's class that listens for the display object to be added to the stage. Only when the event listener recieves this event will you have a reference to the stage:

Main.as(document class):

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class Main extends Sprite
    {
        public function Main()
        {
            if(stage) init()
            else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

        }// end function

        public function init(e:Event = null):void
        {   
            var foo:Foo = new Foo();
            addChild(foo);

        }// end function

    }// end class

}// end package
```

Foo.as:

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class Foo extends Sprite
    {
        public function Foo()
        {
            if(stage) init()
            else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

        }// end function

        public function init(e:Event = null):void
        {   
            if(stage) trace("success"); // output: success

        }// end function

    }// end class

}// end package
```

**OPTION 3**

Yet another option is to store the reference to the stage in a class that can be accessed globally. To do this you use static public properties or methods to set and get the reference of the stage directly to and from the class:

Main.as(document class):

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class Main extends Sprite
    {
        public function Main()
        {
            if(stage) init()
            else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

        }// end function

        public function init(e:Event = null):void
        {   
            GlobalVars.stage = stage;

            var foo:Foo = new Foo();

        }// end function

    }// end class

}// end package
```

GlobalVar.as:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Stage;

    public class GlobalVars
    {
        public static var stage:Stage;

    }// end class

}// end package
```

Foo.as

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.Stage;

    public class Foo
    {
        public function Foo()
        {
            var stage:Stage = GlobalVars.stage;
            if(stage) trace("success"); // output: success

        }// end function

    }// end class

}// end package
```

**[UPDATE]**

Looking at your code I just couldn't figure out why your `xmlReader` class extends  `DisplayObject` in the first place. `xmlReader` seemingly handles all xml related logic like loading and intepreting xml, so why not leave it at that? Let another class handle the object on the stage. I think the real solution to your problem is a better code structure, the following is an example of this:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.text.TextField;

    public class Main extends Sprite
    {
        public function Main()
        {
            if(stage) init()
            else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

        }// end function

        public function init(e:Event = null):void
        {   
            var textField:TextField = new TextField();
            textField.name = "textField";
            stage.addChild(textField);

            var stageManager:StageManager = new StageManager(stage, "dummy.xml");

        }// end function

    }// end class

}// end package

import flash.display.Stage;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.text.TextField;

class StageManager
{
    private var _stage:Stage;
    private var _xmlReader:XMLReader;

    public function StageManager(stage:Stage, url:String)
    {
        _stage = stage;
        _xmlReader = new XMLReader(url);
        _xmlReader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onXMLReaderComplete);

    }// end function

    private function onXMLReaderComplete(e:Event):void
    {
        var textField:TextField = _stage.getChildByName("textField") as TextField;
        textField.text = "XML LOADED!";

    }// end function

}// end class

import flash.events.EventDispatcher;
import flash.net.URLLoader;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.events.IOErrorEvent;
import flash.errors.IOError;


class XMLReader extends EventDispatcher
{
    public var xml:XML;

    public function XMLReader(url:String) 
    {
        read(url);

    }// end function

    public function read(url:String)
    {
        var urlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(new URLRequest(url));
        urlLoader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onURLLoaderIOError);
        urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onURLLoaderComplete);

    }// end function

    private function onURLLoaderIOError(e:IOErrorEvent):void
    {
        throw new IOError(e.text);

    }// end function

    private function onURLLoaderComplete(e:Event):void
    {
        xml = URLLoader(e.target).data as XML;
        dispatchEvent(new Event(Event.COMPLETE));

    }// end function

}// end class
```

Comment: Fantastic answer - it was good to see a well thought out approach, esp. around the pass by reference. Too many people still do it the 'as2' way and use parent.parent.parent.... (or _parent._parent._parent....).

Comment: @Chris thanks, and I completely agree with you. Climbing up the display list via `parent.parent.parent // ...` is a bad way to gain access to another object(unless your dealing with a composite structure). The only bad thing about parsing a reference is that it can make your classes too tightly coupled. I also wanted to add another option where you send a reference of the stage via an event, but I thought that wouldn't really be necessary in this case.

Comment: Great help ... thank you ! .. "xmlReader" was just an uncomplete example and is not important at all .

Comment: @ah ok, well I'm glad if this helped.